# Appbarの色が白いままで変わりません。

Tags: flutter, dart

現在、Flutterで「避難所マップ」を作成中です。
VS Codeでプロジェクト作成後、デフォルトのカウントアプリのコードを削除して
避難所検索ページのUIを作成していたのですが、デフォルトで表示されていたはずのメニューバーの色が白くなってしまいます。

以下の動画を参考に、元動画ではトイレを探すページとして作成したページをもとに、search＿escape_page.dartで以下のようなコードを作成し、Appbarを追記してから、背景が白くなってしまっています。

[位置情報APIを使ったFlutterアプリ開発 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8qIdW0eMnE&t=174s)

元動画では、main.dart内に記載されているデフォルトの背景色が反映されるはずかもしれないのですが、私がデフォルトのコードを削除してしまってからは全く反映されません。

元動画の確認や開発環境をWindowsからMac、エミュレーター環境もAndroidからiOSに変更など色々試したのですが、一切解決できません。ご指導・ご進達の程よろしくお願いします。

**現在のコード:**

```
theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,

      ),

       import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class SearchEscapePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const SearchEscapePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<SearchEscapePage> createState() => _SearchEscapePageState();
    }
    
    class _SearchEscapePageState extends State<SearchEscapePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network(''),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**現在の状態:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]